# ClassNotFoundException when running hadoop jar

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, mapreduce

I'm attempting to run a MapReduce job from a `jar` file and keep getting a `ClassNotFoundException` error.  I'm running Hadoop 1.2.1 on a Centos 6 virtual machine.

First I compiled the file `exercise.java` (and class) into a jar file `exercise.jar` using the following shell script `compile.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

javac -classpath /pathto/hadoop-common-1.2.1.jar:\
/pathto/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar /pathto/exercise.java

jar cvf exercise.jar /pathto/*.class
```

This runs fine and the jar completes successfully.  I then attempt to run the actual MapReduce job using shell script `exec.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/pathto/hadoop-common-1.2.1.jar:\
/pathto/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/pathto/exercise.class

hadoop jar exercise.jar exercise /data/input/inputfile.txt /data/output
```

This trows the `ClassNotFoundException` error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: exercise
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

I realize the explicit path names might not be necessary but I've been a little desperate to double check everything.  I've confirmed that in my `exercise.java` file `exercise.class` is in the job configuration via `job.setJarByClass(exercise.class);` and confirmed `exercise.class` is contained in `exercise.jar`.  Can't seem to figure it out.

**UPDATE**
The exec.sh script with the full path of `exercise.class`.  It's stored in my Eclipse project directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/pathto/hadoop-common-1.2.1.jar:\
/pathto/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/home/username/workspace/MVN_Hadoop/src/main/java.com.amend.hadoop.MapReduce/*

hadoop jar \
exercise.jar \
/home/username/workspace/MVN_Hadoop/src/main/java.com.amend.hadoop.MapReduce/exercise \
/data/input/inputfile.txt \
/data/output
```

When I actually try and run the exec.sh script using the explicitly written out path names, I also get a completely different set of errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /home/hdadmin/workspace/MVN_Hadoop/src/main/java/come/amend/hadoop/MapReduce/exercise
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

Comment: Presumably the class is defined as `Exercise` inside of `exercise.java` if you followed Java conventions. Try doing `hadoop jar exercise.jar Exercise /data/input/inputfile.txt /data/output` (capital `E`)

Comment: You shouldn't be using `/home/username/workspace/MVN_Hadoop/src/main/java.com.amend.hadoop.MapReduce/exercise` since that is your **local filesystem** and not a Java class file

Comment: @cricket_007 I originally didn't do that, just placed it there per srikanth's request below.  If I remove it though, still get the original error...

Comment: Yes, you get a different error because your JAR file doesn't contain that path.  Like I said that's your local disk, which HDFS nor the JAR know how to read. The argument after the jar file simply needs to be the name of the class file contained within the JAR file. You can give package names, but not a location on disk.

Comment: @cricket_007 I get what you're saying, but if I just keep it to 'hadoop jar exercise.jar exercise /data/input/inputfile.txt /data/output' (with exercise being the name of the class in the jar file) I still get the original error.

Comment: @cricket_007 OH are you saying I shouldn't be writing the explicitly in my compile.sh script as well?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that second comment. And I've never bundled a JAR from the terminal, so I'm not too sure you did that correctly. I do know you'll need a manifest file in the JAR to specify the main class file.

Comment: @cricket_007 alright you have me something to think about...maybe I've compiled my jar file incorrectly...give me a second to update

Answer (score 0):

I could see this possible errors.
From the *Hadoop jar exercise.jar exercise /data/input/inputfile.txt /data/output* please specify the full path of the exercise class. I.e *org.name.package.exercise* if exists. To cross check open the jar file and check the location of exercise.class location. 
To continue, Hadoop doesn't expect jars to be included within the jars, since the path of Hadoop is set globally.

NEW:
See, the following path is some thing weird. "/home/hdadmin/workspace/MVN_Hadoop/src/main/java/come/amend/hadoop/MapReduce/exercise"

If you are running using your jar, how could a class path be so specific, instead of jar path. It could only be "come/amend/hadoop/MapReduce/exercise" this.

Comment: sorry for the late reply but I updated my question with your request.  Thanks!